# FeatureCollection.geometry() shortcut no longer working to return a single geometry from the features of a FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

Up until sometime in the last week or so, the following code was working to convert the features of a filtered FeatureCollection into a single multipolygon geometry:

```
var predicates = ee.Filter.inList('GEOID', countylist);
var unioncounties = ee.FeatureCollection(counties.filter(predicates).geometry());
```

Now however, the features all remain separate and I have to use the following to get a single geometry, which is much slower:

```
var predicates = ee.Filter.inList('GEOID', countylist);
var unioncounties = ee.FeatureCollection(counties.filter(predicates).geometry().dissolve());
```

Anybody else seeing this change of behavior?

**UPDATED TO EXCLUDE COUNTIES WITH LINESTRINGS** from Noel's answer below.  Still,  .geometry() no longer is merging the features into a single geometry like it did a month ago.  It does not matter what FC is used, the behavior has somehow changed:

Full working code example here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6d3c7110f0994cfde2a467cd9ee3911b

Answer (score 0):

One of the counties has an extra linestring in the geometry.

```
GeometryCollection
    type: GeometryCollection
    geometries: List (5 elements)
        0: LineString, 2 vertices
        1: Polygon, 727 vertices
        2: Polygon, 3920 vertices
        3: Polygon, 1778 vertices
        4: Polygon, 3687 vertices
```

Since there are different types of geometries in the result, you get a GeometryCollection instead of a simple MultiPolygon when you take the geometry of the collection (which is a little dangerous to do anyway; e.g.: if the polygons ever overlap, you get the difference in the overlapping regions).  You can filter out the linestring with a map (or as you found, just flatten it with a a dissolve):

```
var filtered = unioncounties.geometries().map(function(g) {
  var type = ee.Geometry(g).type();
  return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(type, "Polygon"), g, null)
}, true)

unioncounties = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(filtered))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense.  However, there must be something else going on as well, as when I shorten the county list to exclude the county that had the linestring, .geometry() still is not merging the geometries anymore. Code:  https://code.earthengine.google.com/fcc920716499736cdda75f9863b5df24   Again, the strange thing is that merging geometries this way was working fine a week or more ago so something must have changed in the EE inner-workings recently. (The code I am using has not changed and it does not seem to matter what FC I test it on, the behavior has changed)

Comment: Updated original question above to show this still is not working even when LineString geometries are excluded